# xslt call java instance method

Tags: xslt

my xsl looks like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" 
xmlns:SimpleDateFormat="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"
xmlns:Date="java.util.Date" exclude-result-prefixes="SimpleDateFormat Date">

<xsl:variable name="s" select="SimpleDateFormat:new(MMM/dd/yyyy-HH/mm/ss/SSS)"/>
<xsl:variable name="date" select="Date:new(number($beginTime))"/>
```

So now how to call the method format(Date date) of instance 's'?

If I use `<xsl:value-of select="s:format($date)" />`, then the error is : prefix must resolve to a namespace : s.

But if I add the namespace like this : `xmlns:s="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"`, the `<xsl:value-of select="s:format($date)" />` will return default format, not the specified format.

So how can I get the specified format, like MM/dd/yyyy-HH/mm/ss/SSS ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The namespace you need to use is the one which refers to the object type, and pass the variable itself as the first argument in your call:

BTW: You need to put the format argument between apostrophes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:SimpleDateFormat="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" xmlns:Date="java.util.Date" exclude-result-prefixes="SimpleDateFormat Date">
    <xsl:variable name="s" select="SimpleDateFormat:new('MMM/dd/yyyy-HH/mm/ss/SSS')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="date" select="Date:new()"/>
    <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <Test>
            <xsl:value-of select="SimpleDateFormat:format($s,$date)" />
        </Test>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, i don't quite understand 'You need to put the format argument between apostrophes'. where to put the format argument?  But appreciate you suggestion very much, according to your tip, i did it.  the only question is `SimpldDateFormat.format(Date date)` should only take 1 argument according to the java doc, but why `SimpldDateFormat:format($s,$date)` is correct?

Comment: About the format: I meant that you need to specify the format string "MMM/dd..." between apostrophes, so `SimpleDateFormat:new('MMM/dd..')` instead of `SimpleDateFormat.new(MMM/ddd...)` which would try interpreting it as an xpath instead of a literal.

Comment: About arguments: Yes, this is correct. When you access instance methods (so non static), you need to put an additional param at the begining to specify which instance of that class (specified by the namespace prefix) you want to use. However, When you access static methods or constructors (such as the `SimpleDateFormat.new` call), you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks Carles Sala!  I got it.

Comment: This was possibly the most clutch answer I've ever found on StackOverflow.  Saved my ass in a crunch.  Thank you Carles and thank you StackOverflow!!

Comment: Thanks Carles, you saved the day. :)